# java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I am trying to write a Flutter package that uses platform specific native code. I aimed to use rtt scanning, android.net.wifi.rtt.WifiRttManager for an indoor localization & positioning project. Neither such package for flutter is not exists nor I didn't see it. Also I am planning to publish this on pub.dev. On the kotlin side this is my code and when I run app from main.dart Error occurs:

```
package com.example.wifi_positioning

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.BinaryMessenger
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import android.net.wifi.rtt.WifiRttManager
import android.os.Build
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    private val METHOD_CHANNEL_NAME = "com.baranacikgoz.wifi_positioning/method"
    private val RTT_STATE_CHANNEL = "com.baranacikgoz.wifi_positioning/rtt_state_channel"
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    private lateinit var wifiRttManager: WifiRttManager

    private var methodChannel: MethodChannel? = null

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)

        //Setup Channels
        setupChannels(this, flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
    private fun setupChannels(context: Context, messenger: BinaryMessenger){
        wifiRttManager = context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_RTT_RANGING_SERVICE) as WifiRttManager

        methodChannel = MethodChannel(messenger, METHOD_CHANNEL_NAME)

        methodChannel!!.setMethodCallHandler{
            call, result ->
            when (call.method) {
                "supportsRtt" -> {
                    result.success(context.packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_WIFI_RTT))
                }
                "isRttAvailable" -> {
                    result.success(wifiRttManager.isAvailable)
                }
                else -> {
                    result.notImplemented()
                }
            }


        }
    }


    private fun teardownChannels(){
        methodChannel!!.setMethodCallHandler(null)
    }
}
```

And this is the debug console:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(15624): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.wifi_positioning/com.example.wifi_positioning.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.net.wifi.rtt.WifiRttManager
E/AndroidRuntime(15624):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3190)
E/AndroidRuntime(15624):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3300)
E/AndroidRuntime(15624):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:211)
E/AndroidRuntime(15624):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1705)
E/AndroidRuntime(15624):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(15624):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
E/AndroidRuntime(15624):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
E/AndroidRuntime(15624):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(15624):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime(15624):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
E/AndroidRuntime(15624):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
E/AndroidRuntime(15624): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type android.net.wifi.rtt.WifiRttManager
E/AndroidRuntime(15624):    at com.example.wifi_positioning.MainActivity.setupChannels(MainActivity.kt:38)
E/AndroidRuntime(15624):    at com.example.wifi_positioning.MainActivity.configureFlutterEngine(MainActivity.kt:29)
E/AndroidRuntime(15624):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onAttach(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:199)
E/AndroidRuntime(15624):    at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onCreate(FlutterActivity.java:459)
E/AndroidRuntime(15624):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6575)
E/AndroidRuntime(15624):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1134)
E/AndroidRuntime(15624):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3143)
E/AndroidRuntime(15624):    ... 10 more
E/AndroidRuntime(17077): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(17077): Process: com.example.wifi_positioning, PID: 17077
E/AndroidRuntime(17077): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.wifi_positioning/com.example.wifi_positioning.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
E/AndroidRuntime(17077):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3029)
E/AndroidRuntime(17077):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3300)
E/AndroidRuntime(17077):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:211)
E/AndroidRuntime(17077):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1705)
E/AndroidRuntime(17077):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(17077):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
E/AndroidRuntime(17077):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
E/AndroidRuntime(17077):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(17077):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime(17077):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
E/AndroidRuntime(17077):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
wifiRttManager = context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_RTT_RANGING_SERVICE) as WifiRttManager
```

Seems `WifiRttManager` is not available on this device?